# Error while executing query for custom object Work Order

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am executing the query for my custom object created in SFDC. but i am getting the following error:

`{'[{"message":"\nSELECT FS_Account_Name__c from FS_Work_Order__c\ERROR at Row:1:Column:34\nsObject type 'FS_Work_Order__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.","errorCode":"INVALID_TYPE"}]'}` Thoough have written the correct table name as given while i created the Custom object. PLease help.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't put in the __c yourself? If you did the object would be FS_Work_Order__c__c!

Comment: Also, make sure the logged in user has access to the object. As the error message states, run a describeGlobal() call to get the list of object names available to the logged in user.

Comment: I think what  @LaceySnr said could be the issue. Check the API name in the object.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to try: does it work properly when run as the system administrator profile? If so then it's certainly a permissions issue. Things to checl

- The object is deployed (Setup > Create > Objects > Edit > Deployment Status)
- The profile has permission to query the object.

If not, does that same query work from inside the developer console? If so I can't think of what it might be, except connecting to production instead of a sandbox or vice versa.